# Create CSR with Bouncy Castle (C#) inclusive EC Curve Name

Tags: c#, bouncycastle

I create a CSR with Bouncy Castle and sign it on HSM (EC Key). It works fine! But in the CSR content (and in the certificate later) there is no EC curve name. Instead, there are the parameters of the curve. Some clients have problems with this, e.g .: Phyton. On the screenshot you can see how OpenSSL does it. How can I force Bouncy Castle to write the curve name in the CSR?

The code for the Adding the Public Key to CSR:

```
IList oids = new ArrayList();
IList values = new ArrayList();
..........

SubjectKeyIdentifier subjectKeyIdentifier = new SubjectKeyIdentifierStructure(publicKey);
X509Extension ski = new X509Extension(true, new DerOctetString(subjectKeyIdentifier));
oids.Add(X509Extensions.SubjectKeyIdentifier);
values.Add(ski);

AttributePkcs attribute = new AttributePkcs(PkcsObjectIdentifiers.Pkcs9AtExtensionRequest,
                  new DerSet(new X509Extensions(oids, values)));
//End Extensions

// SIGN on HSM
Pkcs10CertificationRequestDelaySigned csr = new Pkcs10CertificationRequestDelaySigned(
                    signatureAlgorithmStr,
                    subject,
                    publicKey,
                    new DerSet(attribute)
                );
......
```

Screenshot: CSR with Bouncy Castle und OpenSSL

[image: Screenshot: CSR with Bouncy Castle und OpenSSL]

Answer (score 1):

The issue isn't with `BouncyCastle`, but rather how the public key is being generated / initialized.
You can either opt for **named curve** or as **expanded group parameters**, but not both.
Technically they are equivalent, but usage wise, they don't mix well with one another. So you will have to generate both if you want to cater to both of those scenarios. 
I don't know how you are initializing the public key, but you *can* convert to a different public key type before signing.

```cs
AsymmetricKeyParameter publicKey = null;
// ... existing public key by some means
var castedPublicKey = (ECPublicKeyParameters)publicKey;
var newPublicKey = new ECPublicKeyParameters(
                castedPublicKey.AlgorithmName
                ,castedPublicKey.Q,
                X9ObjectIdentifiers.Prime256v1);
// ... rest of code
// SIGN on HSM
Pkcs10CertificationRequestDelaySigned csr = new Pkcs10CertificationRequestDelaySigned(
                    signatureAlgorithmStr,
                    subject,
                    newPublicKey,
                    new DerSet(attribute)
                );
```

*Change `Prime256v1` to whatever curve you are using*

Comment: Thanks, it helped.
When I query the EC-Public from HSM and create it from the EC-Point, I have to use "NamedCurve" -> X9ObjectIdentifiers.Prime256v1
It works. Thank you!

Comment: ECPublicKeyParameters pubKeyParameters = new ECPublicKeyParameters("ECDSA", ecPoint, X9ObjectIdentifiers.Prime256v1);

Comment: Glad it helped, you can upvote or mark the answer as accepted if it helped resolved the issue